# Azure Pipelines + Maven: Unable to locate executable file: 'mvn'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm getting `##[error]Unhandled: Unable to locate executable file: 'mvn'` in Azure devops
 when using an `azure-pipelines.yaml` file like this.

```
trigger:
  - releases/*

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-18.04"

container: mcr.microsoft.com/java/jdk:11-zulu-ubuntu

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'package'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'
```

Possibly related:

- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8630#issuecomment-430751485

Comment: probably not, that one is 2 years old. are you using a hosted agent?

Comment: @4c74356b41: Yes. I'm using `ubuntu-18.04` as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops, which states maven 3.6 is supposed to be included - https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I was a bit confused about the `container: mcr.microsoft.com/java/jdk:11-zulu-ubuntu` part.

The `jib` config I had already used this, so I didn't actually need this in my `azure-pipelines.yml` file.

Comment: @snakesNbronies , Did you get solution ?